# warning:return from incompatible pointer type (enabled by default)

Tags: c, function, pointers, constants

I coded a function. It gets 1 string and 1 character that entered. Character is start point and it prints as from this character. But my code gives 2 errors. Can you help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * mystrchr(const char * from, char c)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; from[i]!='\0'; i++)
        if(from[i]==c)

    return (const *)from+i;

return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char *a;

    a=mystrchr("asdfg","d" );

    printf("%s", a);

return 0;
}
```

Note: One of warnings doesn't fit on title. Therefore, I wrote there:

Passing argument 2 of 'mystrchr' makes  integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

Comment: `return from incompatible pointer type` is because `(const *)` casts to `const int*` (implicit `int` rule, C89).

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * mystrchr(const char * from, char c) {
   int i;
   for(i=0; from[i]!='\0'; i++)
      if(from[i]==c)
         return from+i;
   return 0;
}

int main() {
    char *a;
    a=mystrchr("asdfg",'d' );
    printf("%s", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you remove the const?

Comment: That was just by mistake. Edited the Original post.

Answer (score 1):

> Passing argument 2 of 'mystrchr' makes integer from pointer without a cast

So you're passing a pointer (`"d"` is of type `char [2]` and it decays into `char *` when passed to a function), but the function expects a `char`, which is an integral type.

Fix: change

```
mystrchr("asdfg", "d");
```

to

```
mystrchr("asdfg", 'd');
```

(notice the single quotes around `'d'` - single quotes denote a `char`, whereas double quotes denote string literals.)

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of one warning using single quotes for 2nd parameter.
you are passing `"d"` pass `'d'` in single quotes. 
like this :
`mystrchr("asdfg", 'd');`

`"d"` is `char*` type while you are accepting the argument in function definition as `char` only hence the warning.

Also change the code `return (const *)from+i;` to `return from+i;` no need to typecast here.

since `a` is `char*` type and you are returning `const char *` type and assigning `const char*` to `char*` so You are getting Incompatible pointer type Warning message

Answer (score 0):

Your function is declared like this

```
char *mystrchr(const char *from, char c)
```

and is designed to return a non-const pointer into the middle of the const `from` string. You must not cast const data to non-const. So you should declare your function like this:

```
const char *mystrchr(const char *from, char c)
```

At which point you can remove the cast in your `return` statement.

```
return from+i;
```

The function would arguably be simpler if it used pointers to iterate:

```
const char *mystrchr(const char *from, const char c)
{
    for (const char *p = from; *p; p++)
        if (*p == c)
            return p;
    return 0;
}
```

---

The other problem is that the literal `"d"` is a null-terminated C string literal rather than `char`. You need to use `'d'` to specify a `char` literal.

Comment: @user1946383 You should pick what you feel to be the best answer and accept it.